# RelayCommand UnitTesting

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mvvm, relaycommand

How to write Unit Test case for RelayCommand when there is a parameter in Execute method.Person is model class in MVVM application.

Something like this:

```
DeleteThanksCommand = 
    new RelayCommand<Person>(param => DeleteThanks(param), CanDeleteThanks());
```

When I tried to write unit Test case like:

```
ViewModel.DeleteThanksCommand.Execute(null);
```

Got error at runtime that cannot convert from string to Person.

Please suggest how to write unit test case for this Relay Command.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question.

Comment: **why it has upvotes?** there is no information to answer this question ... what is `RelayCommand` (it's not a part framework) ... there is no info on what is `DeleteThanks` nor `CanDeleteThanks`  **it seems like Ashwin is using sockpuppet account to upvotes his question**

Comment: RelayCommand is a part of WPF which comes under .Net framework. DeleteThanksCommand is a RelayCommand which is binded to the View of class. It's MVVM pattern.

Comment: *RelayCommand is a part of WPF which comes under .Net framework.* [No, it is not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?search=RelayCommand&scope=.NET)  ... You need to post [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/ This information is sufficient for guy having experience in WPF.

Comment: What happens if you pass empty object of person like new Pearson() or you type cart to null person explicitly like (Person)null?

Comment: Thanks,Will try that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel.DeleteThanksCommand.Execute("");
This will work and with help of Assert we can validate O/P with respect to I/P